# How can I create keystore from an existing certificate (abc.crt) and abc.key files?

Tags: ssl, keytool

I am trying to import a certificate and a key file into the keystore but I'm unable to do that.

How can I create a keystore by importing both an existing certificate (abc.crt) and abc.key files?

Answer (score 176):

The easiest is probably to create a PKCS#12 file using OpenSSL:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in abc.crt -inkey abc.key -out abc.p12
```

You should be able to use the resulting file directly using the `PKCS12` keystore type.

If you really need to, you can convert it to JKS using `keytool -importkeystore` (available in `keytool` from Java 6):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore abc.p12 \
        -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
        -destkeystore abc.jks \
        -deststoretype JKS
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, Can you please let me know from where I can get openssl utility?

Comment: One more question here, is generated keystore platform specific?

Means will it work if I create keystore in windows and use it in unix?

Comment: The generated keystore is platform independent. OSX and most Linux distributions should come with OpenSSL (otherwise, just install the package). There are binaries for Windows too ([here](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html), for example, although you can probably find other places too.)

Comment: I should also point out that with a `PKCS12` keystore, the keys password is the same as the store's password (whereas they may be different for other types of stores, especially `JKS`).

Comment: Where does the password that must be used in KeyStore.load() come from? I don't think there's one already set in the `.key` file I have, because `openssl rsa -text` is able to display something that looks like a valid private key.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, it's possible that your private key file isn't password-protected, you'll have to set one up when you create he PKCS#12 file.

Comment: soo suppose i don't have the private keystore, anyway to convert from .crt to .jks?

Comment: @Bruno Thanks. I have s pkcs #7 certificate. Should I have to use pkcs12 or 7 ?

Comment: Note: I think something changed in Java 10's keytool. It was not generating a "Java KeyStore" file. Changed it to Java 8's keytool and it worked as expected.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using openssl/keytool? Like doesn't Java have built-in functionality to import a separate crt and key into a in-memory Keystore?

Answer (score 45):

You must use OpenSSL and keytool.

*OpenSSL for CER & PVK file > P12*

> openssl pkcs12 -export -name **servercert** -in **selfsignedcert.crt** -inkey **serverprivatekey.key** -out **myp12keystore.p12**

*Keytool for p12 > JKS*

> keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore **mykeystore.jks** -srckeystore **myp12keystore.p12** -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias **servercert**

Comment: where is the private key?

Comment: that's what i don't understand!!

Comment: How is this different from the other earlier answer??

Comment: Thanks. I have s pkcs #7 certificate. Should I have to use pkcs12 or 7 ?

Comment: Please note the options which we are passing -name ( for PKCS) -alias (for Jks).

Comment: When creating a new jks file:
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <servercert> does not exist`

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @MK Yung and @Bruno's answer.. Do enter a password for the destination keystore. I saw my console hanging when I entered the command without a password.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in abc.crt -inkey abc.key -out abc.p12 -name localhost  -passout pass:changeit
```

Comment: Thanks! I've also got hanged console and it helped to tackle it

Answer (score 6):

Ideally you should have received 3 files:
ca_bundle.crt yourname.crt yourname.key

Use the following command to create the pk cs 12 version of it with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out yourname.pfx -inkey yourname.key -in yourname.crt -certfile ca_bundle.crt
```

Then you will need to import it into key store that is easy to configure in Apache

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore yourname.pfx -srcstorepass yourpassword -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore yourkeystore.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass yourkeystorepassword
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Bruno's answer, you need to supply the `-name` for alias, otherwise Tomcat will throw `Alias name tomcat does not identify a key entry` error

Sample Command:
`openssl pkcs12 -export -in localhost.crt -inkey localhost.key -out localhost.p12 -name localhost`

Answer (score 2):

If the keystore is for tomcat then, after creating the keystore with the above answers, you must add a final step to create the "tomcat" alias for the key:

```
keytool -changealias -alias "1" -destalias "tomcat" -keystore keystore-file.jks
```

You can check the result with:

```
keytool -list -keystore keystore-file.jks -v
```

Answer (score -1):

## Creating a java keystore given a certificate and private key

A java keystore can be created by importing a pkcs12 keystore into a new java keystore

#### Step 1: create a pkcs12 keystore

*certificate.crt - type in your actual certificate file name
(if its in a different location type in the location - /path/to/certificate.crt)*

*privatekey.key - type in your privatekey
(if its in a different location type in the location - /path/to/privatekey.key)*

*keystore-name.p12 - replace it with your desired keystore name
(i.e., example-com.p12)*

*some-alias - how your certificate and key are recognized in the store
I recommend using the name of the domain (e.g. example.com)*

`-CAfile ca.crt -caname root` - *The command is optional
ca.crt - contains root and intermediate certificates for your certificate authority*
*some certificates (i.e., certificate.crt) define the whole certificate chain hence
specifying the -CAfile is optional*

*Or rather append the ca_bundle.crt into certificate.crt to avoid specifying the -CAfile*
`cat ca_bundle.crt >> certificate.crt`

*finally input a unique keystore password for your pkcs12 keystore and ought to remember it*

> openssl is not preinstalled in windows. You can use git for windows. C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey privatekey.key \
    -out keystore-name.p12 -name some-alias \
    -CAfile ca.crt -caname root
```

#### Step 2: import the pkcs12 keystore, creating a new javakeystore

*keystorepassword - a unique keystore password that you ought to remember for your keystore*

*keypass - a unique key password that you ought to remember for your key*

*javakeystore.jks - replace it with your desired keystore name
(e.g., example-com.jks)*

*keystore-name.p12 - the pkcs12 keystore that you've just created
(if its in a different location type in the location - /path/to/keystore-name.p12)*

*keystorepassword - the keystorepassword that you created*

*some-alias - how your certificate and key are recognized in the store
I recommend using the name of the domain (e.g. example.com)*

```
keytool -importkeystore \
    -deststorepass keystorepassword -destkeypass keypassword \
    -destkeystore javakeystore.jks \
    -srckeystore keystore-name.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass keystore-password \
    -alias some-alias
```