# How to create keystore from cer files?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a problem with the creation of keystore from cer files.

I have three files:

1. NameCertyfikat2015.cer
2. NameIntermediateCA.cer
3. NamePrivateKey.txt

And I want to get jks Keystore file. How can I do this using keytool? I need that file for wildfly container.

My NamePrivateKey.txt start with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i create keystore from an existing certificate (abc.crt) and abc.key files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952274/how-can-i-create-keystore-from-an-existing-certificate-abc-crt-and-abc-key-fil)

Answer (score 1):

ADDED 4/21: Found duplicates:

- [How can i create keystore from an existing certificate (abc.crt) and abc.key files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952274/how-can-i-create-keystore-from-an-existing-certificate-abc-crt-and-abc-key-)
- [convert certificate from pem into jks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296312/convert-certificate-from-pem-into-jks)
- [importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906402/importing-an-existing-x509-certificate-and-private-key-in-java-keystore-to-use-i)

`keytool` does not handle private keys directly.

The *normal* process is:

1. `keytool -genkeypair` the privatekey and publickey *in* a JKS
2. `keytool -certreq` generate a CSR *from* that keypair
3. send the CSR (and related evidence) to a CA to get a certificate
4. `keytool -importcert` the certificate, plus any needed intermediate or "chain" certficate(s), *into* the *same* JKS

If you don't have the JKS with the privateKey in it, but your PrivateKey.txt file contains the private key in a format usable by openssl -- does it begin with a `-----BEGIN` line followed by some lines of base64 and a matching `-----END` line and if so what is the type named after BEGIN? -- and you have or get openssl, you can use openssl to combine the privatekey and the related certs into a *PKCS#12* file, and then `keytool` can convert the PKCS#12 to a JKS like this:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore p12file -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore jksfile
```

Or according to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3686 (sufficiently recent?) Wildfly can use a PKCS12 keystore as-is (*instead* of JKS).

EDIT 4/21: Documentation for the openssl `pkcs12` utility is in a man page on your system if Unix-like with OpenSSL installed (typically section 1ssl or similar), or online at https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html#FILE-CREATION-OPTIONS, or in the duplicates above, or also [Convert a CERT/PEM certificate to a PFX certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate)

Comment: I edit my question and add another information about my privatekey.
But how to use openssl to create pcks112 keystore ?

Comment: @luckybastard yes PEM type "RSA PRIVATE KEY" is handled by OpenSSL (and little else except things using/wrapping OpenSSL like stunnel and curl); for pkcs12 see edits