# How to configure ssl in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, keytool, jks

I need my restful service support ssl in spring boot. Though the service app started successfully, I fail to access the page in Chrome(version:68.0.3440.106). The error message：ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Captured image of error message:
[image: error message]

pom.xml of the project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-restful-server-https</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

configuration file (passwords have been masked intentionally):

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:shq.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
server.ssl.key-password=******
```

Controller class:

```
package test.spring_restful_server_https;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

I use java keytool to generate the shq.jks file.
keytool command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias shq -keystore shq.jks
```

after execute:

```
keytool -list -keystore shq.jks -v
```

jks file infomation (my enviroment is chinese, so I translate the information and put in parenthesis):

```
密钥库类型（keystore type）: JKS
密钥库提供方(keystore provider): SUN

您的密钥库包含 1 个条目(your keystore contains 1 entry)

别名(alias name): shq
创建日期(creation date): 2018-8-16
条目类型(entry type): PrivateKeyEntry
证书链长度(certificate chain length): 1
证书(certificate)[1]:
所有者(owner): CN=shq, OU=home, O=home, L=shanghai, ST=shanghai, C=cn
发布者(issuer): CN=shq, OU=home, O=home, L=shanghai, ST=shanghai, C=cn
序列号(serial number): 279abe96
有效期开始日期(valid from): Thu Aug 16 21:02:31 CST 2018, 截止日期(until): Wed Nov 14 21:02:31 CST 2018
证书指纹(certificate fingerprints):
         MD5: 78:E1:91:21:04:AC:38:F1:0B:30:D8:51:69:FD:BE:28
         SHA1: 8A:D5:1C:26:69:6B:5C:50:75:A6:E8:BE:66:2F:58:01:68:8F:78:1A
         SHA256: 74:0F:F1:0D:59:75:93:3B:BD:55:75:3D:F1:E8:23:17:CE:5D:C0:14:63:0D:D9:53:54:29:C2:C4:70:5A:82:C0
         签名算法名称(signature algorithm name): SHA1withDSA
         版本(version): 3

扩展(extensions):

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: AF 9F 16 35 95 36 FD 13   0C EA 19 F8 A0 D0 E3 6F  ...5.6.........o
0010: A6 CB BB EE                                        ....
]
]
```

Comment: what's the translation of the error message after 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace on the server side as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot https with valid cert get ERR\_SSL\_VERSION\_OR\_CIPHER\_MISMATCH, self signed works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815305/spring-boot-https-with-valid-cert-get-err-ssl-version-or-cipher-mismatch-self-s)

Comment: i think you should paste the **keytool command** to show how you generate the jks file

Comment: there is no error stacktrace on the server side@LuiggiMendoza

Comment: I read the post which you referred, maybe there are some differences: I used jks to generate self signed certificate, however that post used certificate issued by a CA.@SimonMartinelli

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have added the keytool command and also the detail of jks file@clevertension

Comment: it means :The website can't provide secure connection. The client and server do not support the general SSL protocol and encryption suite.@zapl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keytool -genkeypair` by default creates a DSA key and (selfsigned) cert, and **Chrome apparently no longer supports any ciphersuites that use DSA** (which SSL/TLS calls DSS for hysterical raisins). I know it did in the past, because I have used it that way, but the last time I'm sure of is quite a while ago. To fix *that* add `-keyalg rsa`. In addition if you're not using a current or recent version of Java, `keytool` may default to 1024 bits, which has been officially forbidden (insecure) for several years now (although I'm *pretty* sure Chrome doesn't yet enforce it on manually-entered certs); to be on the safe side also add `-keysize 2048`.

But that won't be enough. `keytool -genkeypair` by default creates a cert with no extensions, and particularly **without the 'SAN' extension** (Subject Alternative Name). SAN has been *recommended* for HTTPS certs since about the beginning of the century, and as of last year Chrome *requires* it. Fortunately recent versions of `keytool` can generate SAN if you [add `-ext SAN=type:value[,...]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#CHDFJFHB). But note the value(s) in SAN **must match** the name *used to connect*: if you tell the browser `https://127.0.0.1:port/` as shown in your post, the cert's SAN must contain an entry for `IP:127.0.0.1`; an entry for a domainname like `DNS:myhost.foo` is a different name and DOES NOT MATCH and will not be accepted, even if `myhost.foo` resolves to address 127.0.0.1. SAN supports multiple entries, so you can have one or more IP(s) and/or one or more DNS(s) if you wish. (If you used another browser you could get away with omitting SAN for now, *if* you do make the Subject field 'CN' (Common Name) match (and it can hold only one value), but I wouldn't take a bet on how much longer.)

And in case you aren't aware, since you didn't mention it, a selfsigned cert like that generated by `keytool` (or by lots of other things like `openssl req -new -x509` which you'll find all over the web including here on Stack) will be considered untrusted and invalid by default. You must add it to the browser's truststore before it will be trusted. Since Chrome uses the underlying system's truststore, you can do this either through Chrome or by other means that vary depending on the system which you didn't identify.
If you are going to access this from other clients, as I assume you will, the truststores used by different clients usually depend on the clients, about which you didn't say anything.

ADDED: It looks like this happened in 2016; they removed all DHE keyexchange as a crude way of preventing too-small DHE aka Logjam, and the only DSA (DSS) keyexchange requires DHE. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=619194

Comment: thanks for your answer, it does make sense to me. As to 'SAN' extension, it was new concept for me, I need some more research by myself to understand it.

Comment: Some places to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951939/chrome-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate also several in serverfault and security.SX