# self-signed certificates and 'Java SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common'

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

I am attempting to create and use self-signed certificates for a spring boot gateway application, but newer versions of some dependencies have exposed a flaw in my certificate generation.  I believe that this is partially addressed (and better described) by [Java SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412374/java-sslhandshakeexception-no-cipher-suites-in-common) but I do not understand the certificate process enough to apply the answer to my situation.

In general, whenever I try to connect to my running application, I receive the error `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common`.  I am not explicitly setting or restricting cipher suites.

##### Certificate Creation

```
openssl genrsa -out myCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out myCA.pem
openssl genrsa -out dev.domain.com.key 2048
openssl req -new -key dev.domain.com.key -out dev.domain.com.csr
vi dev.domain.com.ext # contents below
openssl x509 -req -in dev.domain.com.csr -CA myCA.pem -CAkey myCA.key -CAcreateserial -out dev.domain.com.crt -days 1825 -sha256 -extfile dev.domain.com.ext
openssl pkcs12 -export -in dev.domain.com.crt -inkey dev.domain.com.key -out myserver.p12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myserver.p12 -destkeystore selfsigned.keystore -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass changeit
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file myCA.pem -keystore selfsigned.keystore
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias myserver -file dev.domain.com.crt -keystore selfsigned.keystore
```

##### Ext file contents

I'm using this file to provide subject alternative names to my self-signed certificate.  I don't think this is related to the error, but am including it for completion just in case.

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = unqualified hostname
DNS.2 = fully qualified hostname
DNS.3 = unqualified alias
DNS.4 = fully qualified alias
```

##### Usage

My actual configuration is fairly application-specific,  but in general I am using `selfsigned.keystore` as my `SSL_KEYSTORE` and `myCA.pem` as my `CERT_AUTHORITY_PEM`.

##### Question

How can I create my self-signed certificates such that the entire chain is trusted by my application?

Comment: *"no cipher suites in common"* - this error has nothing to do with certificate validation, i.e. it does not matter for this error that you use a self-signed certificate here.

Comment: Well, the same application works with a CA-generated certificate.

Comment: Available ciphers depend only in one aspect on the certificate: ciphers requiring RSA  based authentication need a RSA certificate (which you have  created) while cipher requiring ECDSA authentication need an ECC certificate. I don't know if this is the difference in the other certificate you have, but in any case it is not about self-signed vs, CA created.

Comment: Interesting; thanks for the clarification!  That could definitely be it...time for more google about ecc cert creation.

Comment: This error usually arises when no certificate has been sent at all, or else when one or both peers has fiddled with the available cipher suites.