# Install CA Certificate in Jboss AS 7.1.1

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, certificate, keytool

Last couple of days I'm trying to incorporate CA certificate in my Jboss AS 7.1.1. But unfortunately I was not able todo that successfully.

Here I need to mention that I have already generated CSR file from my system and uploaded to CA authoroty's website and in turn they provided zip file to download. For this I just selected "Tomcat" as the server type.There was a list where other options to select are "IIS", "Apache", "Exchange".... "Tomcat", "Other". In turn the zip file was provided and that file contains one .PEM, one root .CRT and one intermediate .CRT.

Now kindly suggest me what to do with these files ? If you can provide specific step by step guideline it would definitely help me.

Thanks in advance.

Jayanta P.

Comment: What command did you used to generate the CSR (would help me give you a step by step instruction if I know what you did). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to create a JKS file so that you can reference that from your standalone.xml. Here's a [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952274/how-can-i-create-keystore-from-an-existing-certificate-abc-crt-and-abc-key-fil) about how to create that file. I don't have my current config file with me but I've configured that on JBoss EAP. I think it shouldn't be very different for AS. Later I'll check how I did it and update my answer.